# Display sum of specific column in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to display sum of amount for particular region.
Below is my code to display the data, however I am sure how to add up the amount.
I am able to read csv file an display in html table.
I am new to Javascript. Any help to proceed would be much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function loadFile(o)
   {
     var fr = new FileReader();
     fr.onload = function(e)
      {
        showDataFile(e, o);
      };
    fr.readAsText(o.files[0]);
   }

 function showDataFile(e, o)
  { 
    var getCSVData = e.target.result;
    var rows = getCSVData.split("\n");
    var html = '<table border="1">';
    rows.forEach((data, index) => 
    {
       html += "<tr>";
       var value = data.split(",");
       var region = value[1];
       var amount =value[3];
        if(region=="SA")
          {
             html += "<td>" + region + "</td>";
             html += "<td>" + amount + "</td>"
          }
       html += "</tr>";
    });
         html += '</table>';  
         document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
         document.getElementById("data").style.color="blue";
   }
   </script>
   <title> Read CSV file using JavaScript  </title>
   </head>
   <body>
    Select file to read <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this)">
    <pre id="data"></pre>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I got below output:SA 359.8
SA 2731.2
SA 8543.68
SA 9926.97
SA 7897
SA 91.91
SA 2170.28

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable that you use as an accumulator to save the result of the sum, for example:

```js
var sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  sum += 10;
} 
console.log(sum)
```

Following your idea, you need to create a variable initialized at 0 before forEach and then inside the loop, accumulate its result

NOTE:
1. When you read your .csv file, it is received as a String, so the value of the variable amount is also a String, so before making the sum it should be transformed to a Number type to avoid concatenate

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function loadFile(o)
   {
     var fr = new FileReader();
     fr.onload = function(e)
      {
        showDataFile(e, o);
      };
    fr.readAsText(o.files[0]);
   }

 function showDataFile(e, o)
  { 
    var getCSVData = e.target.result;
    var rows = getCSVData.split("\n");
    var html = '<table border="1">';
    var sum = 0;
    rows.forEach((data, index) => 
    {
       html += "<tr>";
       var value = data.split(",");
       var region = value[1];
       var amount = value[3];
        if(region=="SA")
          {
             if (Number(amount)) {
               sum += Number(amount)
             }
             html += "<td>" + region + "</td>";
             html += "<td>" + amount + "</td>"
          }
       html += "</tr>";
    });
         html += '</table>'; 
         html += '<span>' + sum + '</span>';
         document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
         document.getElementById("data").style.color="blue";
   }
   </script>
   <title> Read CSV file using JavaScript  </title>
   </head>
   <body>
    Select file to read <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this)">
    <pre id="data"></pre>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thankyou Mate !! Now If I want to display only the Total amount (not all the rows) and Region "SA" , how would I do that?\

Comment: Also how  to display total for each region in same table?Which loop condition should I use?

Comment: 1. To show only the sum, then you must stop saving in the "html" variable inside the loop

Comment: 2. There are many ways to do it, possibly an object type variable can help you a lot (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) and also reading about map could give you more ideas (https: // developer. mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: I wish to display total for each region. Regions are SA,NSW, QLD.I tried using js_objects but could display only first region and total of all 3

Comment: I would use an object, but the simplest method is to create three variables, for example (totalAmounSA, totalAmountNSW and totalAmountQLD) instead of the variable "sum" and add in the loop the conditions by region like the line "if (region == "SA") "and save your different sums in the three vars.